# How can I convert this code to meta-programming, so I can stop duplicating it?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, dry

I've got a small but growing framework for [building .net systems with ruby / rake](http://albacorebuild.net) , that I've been working on for a while now. In this code base, I have the following:

```
require 'rake/tasklib'

def assemblyinfo(name=:assemblyinfo, *args, &block)
  Albacore::AssemblyInfoTask.new(name, *args, &block)
end

module Albacore
  class AssemblyInfoTask < Albacore::AlbacoreTask
    def execute(name)
      asm = AssemblyInfo.new
      asm.load_config_by_task_name(name)
      call_task_block(asm)
      asm.write
      fail if asm.failed
    end
  end
end
```

the pattern that this code follows is repeated about 20 times in the framework. The difference in each version is the name of the class being created/called (instead of AssemblyInfoTask, it may be MSBuildTask or NUnitTask), and the contents of the execute method. Each task has it's own execute method implementation.

I'm constantly fixing bugs in this pattern of code and I have to repeat the fix 20 times, every time I need a fix.

I know it's possible to do some meta-programming magic and wire up this code for each of my tasks from a single location... but I'm having a really hard time getting it to work.

my idea is that I want to be able to call something like this:

```
create_task :assemblyinfo do |name|
  asm = AssemblyInfo.new
  asm.load_config_by_task_name(name)
  call_task_block(asm)
  asm.write
  fail if asm.failed
end
```

and this would wire up everything I need.

I need help! tips, suggestions, someone willing to tackle this... how can I keep from having to repeat this pattern of code over and over?

**Update:** You can get the full source code here: http://github.com/derickbailey/Albacore/ the provided code is /lib/rake/assemblyinfotask.rb

Comment: +1 for use of Github, very nice to be able to browse the whole source.

Comment: Why don't you just place all the class defs into the module file?  The metaprogramming approach then only saves you 1 real (non-"end") line of code, while coming at the expense of extra obfuscation.  Unless you need to dynamically define the tasks, I'd just use the vanilla approach.

Comment: . . . unless of course this is meant to be more of a learning exercise than a finished project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here's some metaprogramming that will do what you want (in ruby18 or ruby19)

```
def create_task(taskname, &execute_body)
  taskclass = :"#{taskname}Task"
  taskmethod = taskname.to_s.downcase.to_sym
  # open up the metaclass for main
  (class << self; self; end).class_eval do
    # can't pass a default to a block parameter in ruby18
    define_method(taskmethod) do |*args, &block|
      # set default name if none given
      args << taskmethod if args.empty?
      Albacore.const_get(taskclass).new(*args, &block)
    end
  end
  Albacore.const_set(taskclass, Class.new(Albacore::AlbacoreTask) do
    define_method(:execute, &execute_body)
  end)
end

create_task :AssemblyInfo do |name|
  asm = AssemblyInfo.new
  asm.load_config_by_task_name(name)
  call_task_block(asm)
  asm.write
  fail if asm.failed
end
```

The key tools in the metaprogrammers tool box are:

- `class<<self;self;end` - to get at the metaclass for any object, so you can define methods on that object
- `define_method` - so you can define methods using current local variables

Also useful are

- `const_set`, `const_get`: allow you to set/get constants
- `class_eval` : allows you to define methods using `def` as if you were in a `class <Classname> ... end` region

Comment: If you want the ability to auto-capitalize etc, you can find that functionality in ActiveSupport.

Comment: i'm using Ruby 1.8.6... i think this solution is for 1.9+

Comment: ActiveSupport can only autocapitalize when you use underscore delimiters, which Derick didn't seem to want.

Comment: this was almost perfect... the metaclass was problematic, and the *args and &block were still not 1.8.6 compliant, but i was able to get around that by changing the method definition to

  Object.class_eval(<<-EOF, __FILE__, __LINE__)
    def #{taskmethod}(name, *args, &block)
      Albacore.const_get("#{taskclass}").new(name, *args, &block)
    end
  EOF

works great! thanks for the help in getting me going on this. i definitely picked up some new tools for my meta-belt. :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, tested on ruby 1.8.6:

```
class String
  def camelize
    self.split(/[^a-z0-9]/i).map{|w| w.capitalize}.join
  end
end

class AlbacoreTask; end

def create_task(name, &block)
  klass = Class.new AlbacoreTask
  klass.send :define_method, :execute, &block
  Object.const_set "#{name.to_s.camelize}Task", klass
end

create_task :test do |name|
  puts "test: #{name}"
end

testing = TestTask.new
testing.execute 'me'
```

The core piece is the "create_task" method, it:

- Creates new class
- adds execute method
- Names the class and exposes it